# How do you jitter points using scatter3d?

Tags: r

I have a 3D plot that I really like and I'm trying to figure out if I can jitter the points in any way. I graphing categorial variables and some of them overlap each other.

What is the syntax for using jitter in 3d plotting?

Here's my code for the plot

```
# regression

x <- average_cluster$Heart_Rate_Cluster
y <- average_cluster$Body_temp_Cluster
z <- average_cluster$Percent_Active_Cluster

fit <- lm(z ~ x + y)

grid.lines = 26
x.pred <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = grid.lines)
y.pred <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = grid.lines)
xy <- expand.grid( x = x.pred, y = y.pred)
z.pred <- matrix(predict(fit, newdata = xy), 
                 nrow = grid.lines, ncol = grid.lines)

fitpoints <- predict(fit)

scatter3D(x, y, z, colvar = as.integer(average_cluster$Classification),
          pch = 20, ticktype = "detailed", cex = 1.5,
          col = c("#1B9E77", "#D95F02","#7570B3"),
          theta = 160, phi = 10, 
          bty = "g",
          main = "Cluster data", 
          xlab = "Lag Air",
          ylab ="Lag Radiation", 
          d = 5,
          zlab = "Lag Wind",
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred,  
                      facets = NA, fit = fitpoints, shade = 0.1, 
                      col = "grey"),
          colkey = list(at = c(1,2,2.8), side = 1, 
                        addlines = TRUE, length = 0.5, width = 0.5,
                        labels = c("Highest", "Lowest", "Middle")))
```

And here is the data set

```
average_cluster <- data.frame(
  X = 1:10,
  Turtle = c(
    "R3L1", "R3L11", "R3L12", "R3L2", "R3L4", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1",
    "R8L4", "R8NAT123"
  ),
  MeanHR = c(
    21.6886497081712, 18.9328813559322, 17.6588833700082, 8.95548715207506,
    12.9387129461585, 20.4428053977273, 15.0832100108814, 16.4188964193433,
    15.075755022071, 26.6644957856944
  ),
  MeanTb = c(
    20.2662236689815, 22.9743998088286, 18.3861903935185, 18.8428125,
    21.9617008101852, 20.4919618055556, 19.1270783213045, 20.1088958333333,
    22.4328795138889, 22.0789053819444
  ),
  MeanPA = c(
    18.6825667236286, 39.037800687567, 20.4402515724717, 16.780045351542,
    18.5773074665079, 25.7482993198571, 26.2546222928209, 13.1302521011765,
    17.9698216735597, 42.1985815619149
  ),
  Heart_Rate_Cluster = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
  Body_temp_Cluster = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  Percent_Active_Cluster = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L),
  Classification = factor(c(
    "low", "high", "middle", "low", "middle", "high", "low", "middle",
    "high", "middle"
  ))
)
```

I would appreciate any help!

My graph looks something like this [image]

Comment: was the answer helpfull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could jitter the points at the time of the plot. Try:

```
scatter3d(jitter(x, amount = 0.1), 
          jitter(y, amount = 0.1), 
          jitter(z, amount = 0.1))
```

update:

just realized you are using `plot3D` package, so, to reproduce your plot, but with jitter

```
scatter3D(jitter(x, amount = 0.1), 
          jitter(y,  amount = 0.1), 
          jitter(z, amount = 0.1), 
          colvar = as.integer(average_cluster$Classification),
          pch = 20, ticktype = "detailed", cex = 1.5,
          col = c("#1B9E77", "#D95F02","#7570B3"),
          theta = 160, phi = 10, 
          bty = "g",
          main = "Cluster data", 
          xlab = "Lag Air",
          ylab ="Lag Radiation", 
          d = 5,
          zlab = "Lag Wind",
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred,  
                      facets = NA, fit = fitpoints, shade = 0.1, 
                      col = "grey"),
          colkey = list(at = c(1,2,2.8), side = 1, 
                        addlines = TRUE, length = 0.5, width = 0.5,
                        labels = c("Highest", "Lowest", "Middle")))
```

[image: without jitter]

[image: with jitter]

hope it helps